# Nancy DependencyResolver

Tags: c#, autofac, nancy

I'm using Nancy Framework and autofac,  i did like this in Bootstrapper :

```
var services = Assembly.Load("ProjectDomain");
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
    .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IValidationHandler<>))
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

but it doesn't work.....

```
ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler =
    DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
```

handler is null!  how to fix it out?  help me, thanks。。。

Comment: I don't believe nancy works with the service locator pattern, in order to access your injected services you'll have to do it in an module or other injected classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're registering the types AsSelf (which is the default autofac behavior). Could you try this?

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(services)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
    .AsImplementedInterface()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```